# Convert JSON from file to List<T>

Tags: c#, json

I am receiving the following exception when attempting to deserialize JSON from a file:
`Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[Data.Models.Customer]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.`

I am not sure why as I have attempted to use JArray.Parse, and JObject.Parse on the file. The file currently only has one record, and that record looks like the following:
`{"FirstName":"thatFirstName","LastName":"thatLastName","Address":{"Street":"mook","City":"sin city","State":"AL","ZipCode":"90989"},"Id":"9304b36a-f1a9-4cd5-91d0-282648104967"}`

The code I'm having troubles with is the following:

```
JArray persistValues = null;
if(File.Exists(fileName))
{
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileName);
    if (info.Length != 0)
    {
        persistValues = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
        File.Delete(fileName);
    }
}

... extraneous code ...

else if(className.Equals("customer"))
{
    Customer customer = this as Customer;
    customer.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    if (persistValues != null)
    {
        List<Customer> customers = persistValues.ToObject<List<Customer>>();
        customers.Add(customer);
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers);
    }
    else
    {
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
    }
}

... extraneous code ...

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    sw.Write(json);
}
```

What am I missing? I can write to the file just fine, but am unable to read and parse the data back in to my objects...

Side note: The error I receive when using JArray is the following: 
`Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your writing only a single Customer object to your file rather than an array that holds a single Customer. Json.Net is complaining that it is expecting to find an array in order to derserialize to a List but it can find only a single Customer.

Calling JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers) will produce a Json array, so be sure that the file your starting out with contains an array of Customer and not a single serialized Customer.

[Serializing collections with Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm)